# Make option to download base64 audio data as mp3 in javascript

Tags: javascript, download, base64, mp3

I have base64 audio data. I can play it. But I need way to give option to user to click on download option and download in mp3 format.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way you can download the base64 audio data as mp3 file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
 
<script>
function myFunction() {
(document.getElementById("audioRecordDownload")).click();
}
</script>
      
  </head>
  <body>
 
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Download</button>

    <a style="display:none" download="audio-file" id="audioRecordDownload" href="data:audio/mp3; base64, yourbase64DataHere">Download audio</a>
  
</body>
</html>
```